# Beckmann rearrangement v/s dehydration of Oximes

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds, reactivity, rearrangements

[image]

In the above question, A is an oxime, which is then reacted with phosphorus pentoxide. Now, phosphorus pentoxide is both a dehydrating reagent and a reagent used for Beckmenn rearrangement, but which reaction will form the major product mostly, ie, which reaction will dominate? My teacher told to consider beckmenn rearrangement with Phosphorus pentoxide, but the answer of this question is **A**, that is, dehydration is favored . What I think from my experience is that aldoximes will favor dehydration, and ketoximes beckmenn rearrangement( dehydration obviously cannot  occur in them), but I am not sure. Please tell the conditions under which any reaction will dominate over other. Also what  would be the answer if phosphorus pentoxide is replaced by phosphorus pentachloride?

Comment: The aldoxime will tend to dehydrate with P2O5 or PCl5. No Beckmann.

Comment: Or, A is the Beckmann product with aldoximes.

Comment: See beckmann fragmentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you think that the mechanism of "Beckmann" and "dehydration" are different?

Answer is **No**. They're essentially the same reaction. Aldoximes undergoes Beckmann rearrangement to form nitriles, or you can say "they dehydrate" (as hinted by Ben Norris in comments)

The mechanism for **Beckmann rearrangement** is as follows,

[image: aldoximes Beckmann rearrangement]

(Source: Wikipedia, Beckmann rearrangement)

**Note:** Just replace $\ce{R1}$ with $\ce{H}$ and then, in the *intermediate* (upper one) after second step, the arrow will be from $\ce{N-R1}$ bond to $\ce{N}$. That's dehydration!

Also, if you replace $\ce{P2O5}$ by $\ce{PCl5}$ or $\ce{H2SO4}$, the answer would be same for all.

Comment: 1) The middle arrow in the intermediate is going in the wrong direction. 2) If you want phosphate to deprotonate intramolecularly, then draw the anti-oxime. 3) This is a dehydration, not a rearrangement. Atoms are not being reconnected as in the Beckmann rearrangement.

Comment: @user55119: due to limited search via Google, I can't find a standard mechanism for dehydration of aldoximes. Hence, I've edited it with Beckmann rearrangement.

Comment: What about Beckmann Fragmentation/abnormal Beckmann?

Comment: The top two arrows in the second  structure need work. R1 with its electron pair migrates to nitrogen as water is lost. Then the electron pair on nitrogen can stabilize the carbocation.

Comment: @user55119: _"...Then the electron pair on nitrogen can stabilize the carbocation."_ - the intermediate which you're talking about is the _lower one in square brackets_. No?

Comment: @Safdar: you can [see here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beckmann_rearrangement) for fragmentation. I think that's a different reaction.

Comment: No, the structure preceding the brackets. What is in the brackets is fine.